# How to get the attachment id from the attachment page url?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-media

I'm trying to get the id of the attachment from the attachment page url.

When creating a custom post, I uploaded media to the post.

The media now has an attachment page - http://localhost/site/custom-post/post-name/screenshot_20211005-091742/

How can I get the attachment id from this url? I've tried the `attachment_url_to_postid` function but this appears to only work for the direct media url e.g. http://localhost/site/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Screenshot_20211005-091742.png

I've also tested for media uploaded directly to the media library http://localhost/site/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/S036662860_0.jpg but `attachment_url_to_postid` returns 0.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [url_to_postid](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/url_to_postid/) instead of `attachment_url_to_postid`, localhost/site/custom-post/post-name/screenshot_20211005-091742/ is a page URL, not a direct file URL.